# Editing a Google Apps Engine file via SSH

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm dealing with a deprecated Google Apps Engine project where I want to make a small change to an HTML file. Since I don't have the dev environment set up, I've edited the file by SSHing into the server and using `sudo nano [file]`.I'm aware that this is probably bad practice, but this is a one-time issue that needs to be fixed quickly.

My changes don't seem to be propagating to the live webapp. Is there some additional step to complete changes to files on the <s>App Engine</s> Compute Engine VM instance to get them to go live? (maybe it is a CDN or cache issue?)

As some context, I know almost nothing about this environment. Thanks!

Comment: You need to [`appcfg.py update myapp/`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Uploading_the_app)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you "edited the file by SSHing into the server".  What server is this? Are you talking about Compute Engine?

Comment: You cant SSH into App Engine's instances, are you working on a Compute engine virtual machine?. if so, where are you editing the files?

Comment: I got the terminology wrong: it's a compute engine VM. I accessed it by navigating to compute > compute engine > vm instances and clicking "SSH" next to the VM instance. There's a github repo that sits in home/ -- that's where I edited the files.

Comment: is it possible this compute Engine is only setup to hold the **"Push to deploy"** feature (AKA Jenkins CI) and not the actual application? (which might be running on App Engine after all). If so, you'll need to **trigger a jenkins build** ( go to <YOURVM-IP>//jenkins/ ) to get those changes to the "live"app